# How to properly have Flask run a threaded task in background on Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

So, basically, I have an infinite while loop that is constantly scraping a website every few minutes. However, in order to kickstart this process, I just navigate to /scraper to start the new thread, and while this works totally fine, I do not want to have to keep routing to /scraper to start the thread should Heroku restart their servers for maintenance. Is there a way I can implement this so that if I route to the home page / I can have only one thread running, since I would rather kickstart the scraper by routing to home page than /scraper.

```
def scrappy():
    while True:
        try:
            print("Loading scraper...")
            exec(open("texas_scraper.py").read()) #time.sleep(300) inside this .py
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: There may be a bug in the code or your environment setup.")
            print(e)
            time.sleep(60)
        continue

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("Someone is on homepage")
    return '''
        <html><body>
        Hi. <a href="/uploads"> Please click here to download the roster.</a>
        </body></html>
        '''

@app.route('/scraper')
def digger():
    t1 = Thread(target = scrappy)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    print("Someone started the scraper")
    return '''
        <html><body>
        Hi. Loading scraper now!
        </body></html>
        '''
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably starting two different processes in Heroku.

Heroku has a `Procfile` that determines what actually starts your application. One is likely starting your web-server as is. [Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#more-process-type-examples).

It is possible to define a second process, this is as simple as adding a new line in the procfile. You can use that new line to start something like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) that can do exactly what you need. Celery is a distributed task queue system that you can use to, for example, schedule a task every n time. This would *also* remove the need for your while loop as you can simply schedule it every 300 seconds.

```
web: flask run
worker: celery worker -A your_app/celery.py
```

There are obviously other alternatives to Celery, find a nice task queue framework that fits your needs. You could even run your webscraper directly, however, this might not restore itself as Celery would in the event of a crash.